# How to send dynamic data collection to Laravel layout blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

How to send dynamic data collection to Laravel layout blade.

in my case my layout file is app.blade.php, and extending this file with all other blades using @extends.

this app.blade.php file contains my navbar and i need to dynamically loop data for navbar fields.

I need to dynamically loop data for navbar fields. (app.blade.php in layouts)

Comment: In your AppServiceProvider, you can add this on boot method : `view()->composer(['app'], function($view) { $view->with('navData', 'This is a dynamic data');  });` now you can access `navData` from `app.blade.php`

Comment: Read documents : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#displaying-data